# Command 'wails' not found in linux, Error installing wails Go

Tags: go, installation, apache-age, wails

I'm trying to install `wails` in `Ubuntu 22.04`.

Go version `go1.20.3` and NPM version `6.14.11` are already installed on my system.

I followed all steps from the [official website tutorial](https://wails.io/docs/gettingstarted/installation/).

There have been no errors with the steps mentioned in above tutorial.

But when I try the following command

```bash
$ wails version
```

or

```bash
$ wails doctor
```

then I get the error

```bash
$ Command 'wails' not found
```

Comment: Use the full path top the executable or add the executables path to your PATH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow These Commands

```
export GOPATH=~/go 
go install github.com/wailsapp/wails/v2/cmd/wails@latest
export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin
source ~/.bashrc
wails version
```

devn@macbook-pro-2 ~ % wails version
v2.4.1

Answer (score 1):

go is already installed in my system

when I run go version command it run correctly

but the directory where go installed that is home/[username]/go/bin/ was not added in PATH environment.

I followed these steps to add it in PATH environment:

1. Opened the terminal
2. Open the `~/.bashrc` file

```bash
$ nano ~/.bashrc
```

3. Go to bottom of the file and add following line

```bash
$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/[username]/go/bin/
```

> ***you should use the actual path of go/bin folder where the go is installed***
>
> *don't forget to add / at the end*

4. Press **Ctrl + X** to exit nano editor, and type **"Y"** to save changes.
5. Finally run the following command

```bash
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

> PATH is successfully added

Now when I run `wails version` command it don't give me any error.

[image: wails version command output]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an environement variable issue, take a look at the faq about that (https://wails.io/docs/guides/troubleshooting/#the-wails-command-appears-to-be-missing)

Adding it to bashrc may not be enough to fix your issue, You should probably set your environement variables in `.profile`. Take a look at those awnsers explaining the avalible files used to set up environement varaibles https://serverfault.com/q/261802

Comment: Thanks for the additional information